# Ошибка POST https:// xxxx/xxx.php net::ERR_ABORTED 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, авторизация

при попытке прочитать данные с закрытой зоны удаленного хоста получаем ошибку 401.

JS file... (находится на localhost)

```js
let api_url = 'https://xxxxx/xxx.php'
let user = 'xxxxx'
let passwd = 'xxxxxx'

fetch(api_url, { 
              method: 'post', 
              headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
                  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(user + ":" + passwd),
                  'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
               mode: 'no-cors',
           })
           .then(response=>response.json())
           .then(json => console.log(json))
           .catch(error=> console.log(error))
```

На удаленном хосте: https://xxxxx/xxx.php

```html
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
 
echo '{"status":"ok"}'; exit;
```

Хостинг руцентр

Вопрос, в чем ошибка? Почему выплывает шибка:
POST https://xxxx/xxx.php net::ERR_ABORTED 401

Если на localhost в JS убираем "mode: 'no-cors'" то получаем другую ошибку:

Access to fetch at 'https://xxxx/xxx.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 1):

При включении `no-cors` заголовок `Authorization` не передается

Comment: а это точно ответ на вопрос?

Comment: "Вопрос, в чем ошибка?" - Ошибка в том, что установлен параметр no-cors и передается заголовок Authorization. При таком сочетании заголовок Authorization передаваться не будет, для сервера запрос будет неавторизованным и он вернет ошибку 401 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Request/mode